# No default database configuration options in CakePHP 2.5 installation from PhpStorm

Tags: php, cakephp, phpstorm

I am installing CakePHP 2.5 from PhpStorm (latest version). No default configuration is available in `database.php`.

How to fix this?

Comment: Is there no `database.php` in your config dir?  Default install  names it something like  `database.default.php`. you need to manually name it to  `database.php`

Comment: Well, this is documented in the manual https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html#cakephp-database-configuration but there is a sad tendency these days that nobody uses them for whatever reason.

Comment: database.php file is available but the code inside is look like this i tried many installations

`<?php

use AD7six\Dsn\Wrapper\CakePHP\V2\DbDsn;

class DATABASE_CONFIG {

/**
 * Define connections using environment variables
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function __construct() {
  $this->default = DbDsn::parse(env('DATABASE_URL'));
  $this->test = DbDsn::parse(env('DATABASE_TEST_URL'));
 }

}
`

Comment: Offtopic: Why yould you use CakePHP 2.5? The latest 2.x release is 2.9.7, and ideally you wouldn't even start any new projects with CakePHP 2.x anymore at all, and use the latest CakePHP 3.x instead.

Comment: Because rest of the companies projects are on cakephp2.5 so we have to stick with the company rules.

Comment: Clearly someone has done work setting up environments that handles DB config differently from the default setup. Why dont you ask the person that set up the project in your company? 
Ive told you how to get the default config file in my answer which is what your question appears to ask for. You dont have any information about the current setup in your question so I'm sorry to say that no-one is gonna have a magic answer for you.

Comment: You dont have knowledge to answer my question , i got my answers .

Answer (score 1):

the default `database.php` in cakephp 2.x should look like this if it's any help

> https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.x/app/Config/database.php.default

Download this file, put it in your apps `app/Config` dir, name it database.php and add your database config to the `$this->default` array